# how can I hide the playlist when loop the video on youtube embed

Tags: youtube-api

set the video play auto and loop, like this

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/lxv445LWbbo?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&mute=1&autoplay=1&autohide=1&loop=1&playlist=lxv445LWbbo

and it will show the playlist on the left of player, like this [image]

my question is how can I hide the playlist??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop videos, then you cannot hide the playlist.

> Currently, the [`loop`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#loop) parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the [`playlist`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#playlist) parameter.

That means without `playlist`, `loop` will not work, and as long as you have the `playlist` parameter, there will be a playlist.